# Multiple type parameters in type class?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

Lets assume I have a type class `Stack` with one instance `List`:

```
class Stack a where
    push :: a -> Integer -> a
    pop :: a -> a
    last :: a -> Integer

data List = Empty | Element Integer List
instance Stack List where
    push list value = Element value list
    pop Empty = error "No elements"
    pop (Element _ list) = list
    last Empty = error "No elements"
    last (Element value _) = value
```

How `Stack` has to be defined in order for `List` to not be limited to `Integer` values?

```
-- class Stack (?) where ...
data List a = Empty | Element a (List a)
-- instance Show (List a) where ...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In that case you can make a multiparameter class:

```
class Stack a b where
    push :: a -> b -> a
    pop :: a -> a
    last :: a -> b
```

and define it with:

```
instance Stack (List b) b where --You don't need to use `b`, but this make it easier to understand
    push list value = Element value list
    pop Empty = error "No elements"
    pop (Element _ list) = list
    last Empty = error "No elements"
    last (Element value _) = value
```

Note that this is not a default (standardized) Haskell feature, and that you will need to turn it on. Either by passing `-XMultiParamTypeClasses` and `-XFlexibleInstances` to the compiler.

Or you can write:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleInstances #-}
```

in the header of your source file.

---

Note that there can be several `b`'s for one `a` for which you define an instance (and vice versa). This can make it hard to work with such classes. Say for instance you write a `Dummy` type:

```
data Dummy = Dummy
```

you can define:

```
instance Stack Dummy b where
    push x = const x
    pop = id
    last = const $ error "Dummy object"
```

Now it means that you have `Stack` instance for every possible `b`, so that you can `push` and `pop` all kinds of stuff to `Dummy` objects.

Comment: Before this I actually tried the same syntax, but only wrote `instance Stack (List a)`. And I forgot to append `FlexibleInstances` to the pragma. Now it works, thank you :)

Comment: If every `a` admits at most a single `b` such that `Stack a b` has an instance, a functional dependency `a->b` can help the type inference machinery significantly. Otherwise, each call to `pop :: a -> a` is ambiguous: `b` can not be determined from the context of `pop`. (Type families could also be used, of course.)

Comment: @chi: IIRC you can add restrictions, such that there will be only one such `b` for an `a`. Will look it up later.

Answer (score 14):

Consider using a higher-kinded class variable. Thus:

```
class Stack s where
    push :: s a -> a -> s a
    pop  :: s a -> s a
    last :: s a -> a

data List a = Empty | Element a (List a)
```

The instance remains exactly as you wrote it (though `List` now has kind `* -> *` instead of `*`):

```
instance Stack List where
    push list value = Element value list
    pop Empty = error "No elements"
    pop (Element _ list) = list
    last Empty = error "No elements"
    last (Element value _) = value
```

This approach is pure Haskell 2010 -- it requires no extensions.

Also, consider making your failures observable; for instance by changing the type of `pop` and `last` to return `Maybe (s a)` and `Maybe a`, respectively.

Comment: This looks also like a great approach to me. And I'm definitely trying `Maybe` :)

Comment: @Cubinator73 This is *usually* the way to go. The multiparameter typeclass approach with a functional dependency (or a single parameter typeclass with an associated type) makes sense if you're considering multiple monomorphic stack types.