# How can I use functions and terms defined in locale after interpretation?

Tags: typeclass, isabelle

(This question is a continuation from [How can I have multiple arbitrary types in a typeclass definiton in Isabelle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69550046/how-can-i-have-multiple-arbitrary-types-in-a-typeclass-definiton-in-isabelle/69557506#69557506) I posted a new question because I thought it was appropriate to. Apologies if this violates Stack Overflow guidelines!)

So the accepted answer from the above link proposed using a locale for the question asked with code:

```
text ‹Create the locale and define equalParams within the body of the locale›
locale mylocale =
   fixes name :: "'a => 'b"
     and params :: "'a => 'p"
begin
fun equalParams :: "'a => 'a => bool" where
"equalParams a b = (params a = params b)"
end

datatype ('b, 'c, 'd) actionT1 = Act (name: 'b) (c: 'c) (d: 'd)

abbreviation params where
  ‹params a ≡ (c a, d a)›


text ‹Instantiate the locale with our parameters.›

text ‹First in a named interpretation:›
interpretation action: mylocale where name = name and params = params
  by unfold_locales

term action.equalParams

text ‹Second in a unnamed interpretation:›
interpretation mylocale where name = name and params = params
  by unfold_locales

term equalParams
```

What I would like to do is use the functions `name`, `params` and `equalParams` outside of the locale, and in functions that have types assumed to be part of the given locale. For example, suppose I have the function

```
fun f :: "'a :: mylocale => 'b => 'c"
.
. <equations go here>
.
```

Since type `'a` is restricted to locale `mylocale`, I should be able to assume that the generic function names from `mylocale` can be called on elements of type `'a`. However, this cannot be done since the output complains that `mylocale` is not a class. What I want in the end is for `mylocale` to be analogous to a Haskell typeclass with multiple type parameters whose instances have access to functions defined in the class. ([Multiple type parameters in type class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32656822/multiple-type-parameters-in-type-class)). Could I please have some help with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Locales are a contract, not additional information on types. So `'a :: mylocale` does not make sense.

The idea is that you define every function in your locale, for example with:

```
context mylocale
begin

fun f :: "'a => 'b => 'c" where
  ...

end
```

and then all your definitions theorems are instantiated when you interprete (i.e., replace the concrete with concrete values) the locale.

I strongly advise to read the [locale documentation](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2021/doc/locales.pdf) to get more details (I linked the 2021 version, replace 2021 by the current year to get the latest answer).